# Created node doesn't have attachEvent property

Tags: requirejs, magento2.3

After updated magento from 2.1 to 2.3 I've got a require js error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for: ModuleName
```

I made an investigation and find out that `require.js` core file in the function `req.load` is trying to create node `document.createElement('script')` and then checks if this node has `attachEvent` property. In my case it's script node. And there is no `attachEvent` property. By this reason I've got an error.
Can somebody explain why it happens? Everything was good before and code seems was the same.